# GraphQL mutation for 2 entities with parent-child relation returns old value for second entity

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

I'm using apollo server.

While mutating data I need to update 2 tables: `location` and `address`.

End of resolver function:

```
const locationUpdated = await db.location.updateLocation(user.id, location);
const addressUpdated = await db.address.updateAddress(user.id, location.address);
return { error: null, location: { ...locationUpdated, address: addressUpdated } };
```

Using GraphQL Playground:

```
mutation {
  updateLocation(
    location: {
      id: 1
      label: "label12"
      address: { 
        city: "city12"
      }
    }
  ) {
    error
    location {
      label
      address {
        city
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As a result I have new `location.label` but old `location.address.city`:

```
{
  "data": {
    "updateLocation": {
      "error": null,
      "location": {
        "label": "label12",
        "address": {
          "city": "city11",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Database is updated correctly. Looks like server uses cache?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following two ways

1. override the server caching setting. [Ref](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/performance/caching/)

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  // ...
  cacheControl: {
    defaultMaxAge: 0,
  },
}));
```

```
type Post @cacheControl(maxAge: 240) {
  id: Int!
  title: String
  author: Author
  votes: Int @cacheControl(maxAge: 30)
  comments: [Comment]
  readByCurrentUser: Boolean! @cacheControl(scope: PRIVATE)
}

type Comment @cacheControl(maxAge: 1000) {
  post: Post!
}
```

2. updating the `id`. [Ref](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#updating-the-cache-after-a-mutation)

```
updateLocation(
    location: {
      id  //from the doc, I saw that the id must be updated as well, you can try take out the hard code `1`
      label: "label12"
      address: { 
        city: "city12"
      }
    }
  )
```

Comment: I don't want to turn off the cache or change life time for an entity. I'd like to refresh cache somehow.

Comment: @koral check my updated answer. I have checked the doc and it may related to the ```id``` update problem. Try update the ```id``` as well when doing a mutation.